# How to keep value of session array after form submit?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm coding a question script with using two php files. One of them is storing my questions answers and one integer value of question. Program is working like that.

For example

```
$kelime[5]["question"] = "Mavi";
$kelime[5]["answer"] = "blue";
$kelime[5]["number"] = 0;
```

Question is 'Mavi' and answer is 'blue'

When it asked me if I give true answer number must increase 1 if number >= 10 don't ask me this question again. But number value never increase it is always same after submit where I am making wrong?

questions.php

```
<?php

$kelime[0]["tr"] = "Sarı";
$kelime[0]["en"] = "yellow";
$kelime[0]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[1]["tr"] = "Kırmızı";
$kelime[1]["en"] = "red";
$kelime[1]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[2]["tr"] = "Yeşil";
$kelime[2]["en"] = "green";
$kelime[2]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[3]["tr"] = "Siyah";
$kelime[3]["en"] = "black";
$kelime[3]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[4]["tr"] = "Beyaz";
$kelime[4]["en"] = "white";
$kelime[4]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[5]["tr"] = "Mavi";
$kelime[5]["en"] = "blue";
$kelime[5]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[6]["tr"] = "Turuncu";
$kelime[6]["en"] = "orange";
$kelime[6]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[7]["tr"] = "Gri";
$kelime[7]["en"] = "grey";
$kelime[7]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[8]["tr"] = "Mor";
$kelime[8]["en"] = "purple";
$kelime[8]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[9]["tr"] = "Pembe";
$kelime[9]["en"] = "pink";
$kelime[9]["nr"] = 0;

$kelime[10]["tr"] = "Altın";
$kelime[10]["en"] = "gold";
$kelime[10]["nr"] = 0;

$sayi = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

?>
```

asking.php

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    require "kelimeler.php";
    $_SESSION['sayi'] = $sayi;
    $_SESSION['kelime'] = $kelime;

    $i = rand(0,4);

    print_r($_SESSION['kelime']);
    setcookie("soru", $_SESSION['kelime'][$_SESSION['sayi'][$i]]["tr"]);
    setcookie("cevap", $_SESSION['kelime'][$_SESSION['sayi'][$i]]["en"]);

?>

<html>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="kelime"><?php echo $_SESSION['kelime'][$_SESSION['sayi']     [$i]]["tr"] ?></div>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input id="cvp" type="text" name="kelime" placeholder="die Antwort">
            <input type="submit" name="gonder" value="SENDEN !"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php

        if (isset($_POST["kelime"])) {

            if ($_POST["kelime"] == $_COOKIE['cevap']) {
                    echo '<div class="bildirim">You are right &#10004</div>';
                    $_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"] = +1;
                    if ($kelime[$i]["nr"] >= 10) {
                        unset($_SESSION['sayi'][$i]);
                    }
            } else {
                    echo '<div class="bildirim">'.$_COOKIE['soru'].' = '.$_COOKIE['cevap'].'</div>';
            }

        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to all from now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is at the beginning of the script:

```
session_start();
require "kelimeler.php";
$_SESSION['sayi'] = $sayi;       // <<<--here
$_SESSION['kelime'] = $kelime;   // <<<--and here
```

It appears you are resetting these session values to the original arrays every time the page loads. You should only initialize them if they are not already set.

```
session_start();
require "kelimeler.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION['sayi'])) {
    $_SESSION['sayi'] = $sayi;
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['kelime'])) {
    $_SESSION['kelime'] = $kelime;
}
```

Then, as the other answer pointed out, `$_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"] = +1;` will not increment the value. Maybe you meant to use `$_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"] += 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Instead

```
$_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"] = +1;
```

You should

```
$_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"]++;
// or $_SESSION['kelime'][$i]["nr"] += 1;
```

The problem here is `= +1` which sets the value to 1 and do not increment.